# What is the difference between Collectors.toConcurrentMap and converting a Map to ConcurrentHashMap via Collectors.toMap supplier option?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, concurrenthashmap, collectors

I want to convert a `Map` into a `ConcurrentHashMap` via Java 8 `Stream` and `Collector` interface, and there are two options I can use.

The first:

```
Map<Integer, String> mb = persons.stream()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                            p -> p.age, 
                                            p -> p.name, 
                                            (name1, name2) -> name1+";"+name2,
                                            ConcurrentHashMap::new));
```

And the second:

```
Map<Integer, String> mb1 = persons.stream()
                                  .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(
                                             p -> p.age, 
                                             p -> p.name));
```

Which one is the better option? When should I use each option?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a difference between them when dealing with parallel streams.

`toMap` -> is a non-concurrent collector

`toConcurrentMap` -> is a concurrent collector (this can be seen from their characteristics).

The difference is that *toMap* will create multiple intermediate results and then will merge then together (the Supplier of such a Collector will be called multiple times), while *toConcurrentMap* will create a **single** result and each Thread will throw results at it (the Supplier of such a Collector will be called only once)

Why is this important? This deals with insertion order (if that matters).

**toMap** will insert values in the resulting Map in encounter order by merging multiple intermediate results (Supplier of that collector is called multiple time as well as the Combiner)

**toConcurrentMap** will collect elements in any order (undefined) by throwing all elements at a common result container (ConcurrentHashMap in this case). Supplier is called only once, Accumulator many times and Combiner never.

The small caveat here is that for a `CONCURRENT` collector to not invoke the merger: either the stream has to have the `UNORDERED` flag - either via the `unordered()` explicit call or when the source of the stream is not ordered (a `Set` for example).

Comment: is it going to be different if stream is not parallel ?, only difference i see it is just adding characteristics flags to the CollectorImpl then it evaluates according to that flags(insertion order), but if its not parallel stream both method acts same except one produce HashMap other produces ConcurrentHashMap, i meant it only effects current stream's behaviour if its parallel.

Comment: @Bolzano in a non-parallel stream, the Combiner will not get called for either implementation. The merging will be done in the Accumulator (called as many elements you have, while the Supplier will be called only once). So yes, the only visible difference is the result you will get : a HashMap vs a ConcurrentHashMap. under the hood toMap calls HashMap::merge, while toConcurrentMap calls ConcurrentHashMap::merge. So if you are doing serial processing why would you ever want ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: We need to ask it to the @KaranVerma , in his question he is not using parallel streams,  I am assuming he is trying cache the values in ConcurrentHashMap to use it in any other time(for thread safe operations), and his question is  simply : "whats the difference of this 2 code block"

Comment: @Bolzano i am just learning stream of java 8. Not using parallel stream at all currentlt.

Answer (score 8):

From `toMap`'s Javadoc :

> The returned Collector is not concurrent. For parallel stream pipelines, the combiner function operates by merging the keys from one map into another, which can be an expensive operation. If it is not required that results are inserted into the Map in encounter order, using toConcurrentMap(Function, Function) may offer better parallel performance.

`toConcurrentMap` doesn't insert the results into the Map in encounter order, but supposed to give better performance.

If you don't care about the insertion order, it is recommended to use `toConcurrentMap` if you are using a parallel stream.