# Java 8 Parallel Stream Concurrent Grouping

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose I have a class as

```
Class Person {
  String name;
  String uid;
  String phone;
}
```

I am trying to group by all the fields of the class. How do i use parallel streams in JAVA 8 to convert a

```
List<Person> into Map<String,Set<Person>>
```

where the key of the map is the value of each field in the class . JAVA 8 the following example groups by a single field, how can i do it for all fields of a class into a single Map?

```
ConcurrentMap<Person.Sex, List<Person>> byGender =
roster
    .parallelStream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(Person::getGender));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by using the `of` static factory method from `Collector`:

```
Map<String, Set<Person>> groupBy = persons.parallelStream()
    .collect(Collector.of(
        ConcurrentHashMap::new,
        ( map, person ) -> {
            map.computeIfAbsent(person.name, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(person);
            map.computeIfAbsent(person.uid, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(person);
            map.computeIfAbsent(person.phone, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(person);
        },
        ( a, b ) -> {
            b.forEach(( key, set ) -> a.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<>()).addAll(set));
            return a;
        }
    ));
```

As Holger in the comments suggested, following approach can be preferred over the above one:

```
Map<String, Set<Person>> groupBy = persons.parallelStream()
     .collect(HashMap::new, (m, p) -> { 
         m.computeIfAbsent(p.name, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(p); 
         m.computeIfAbsent(p.uid, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(p); 
         m.computeIfAbsent(p.phone, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(p); 
     }, (a, b) -> b.forEach((key, set) -> {
         a.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<>()).addAll(set));
     });
```

It uses the overloaded `collect` method which acts identical to my suggested statement above.

Comment: There is no need to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` here, an ordinary `HashMap` will do. You would need a `ConcurrentHashMap` if you specified the `CONCURRENT` characteristic. You can, by the way, simplify the solution further by using the three-arg version of `collect`: `persons.parallelStream() .collect(HashMap::new, (m, p) -> { m.computeIfAbsent(p.name, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(p); m.computeIfAbsent(p.uid, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(p); m.computeIfAbsent(p.phone, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(p); }, (a, b) -> b.forEach((key, set) -> a.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<>()).addAll(set)));`

Comment: @Holger Well i used the concurrent hash map because OP was talking about parallel. But forgot to add the characteristics. Also edited your part into the answer

Comment: A `Collector` without the `CONCURRENT` characteristic still can be used with a parallel stream. In that case, the Stream implementation takes care to use the functions appropriately; that’s why it works with arbitrary collections and maps and doesn’t require a `ConcurrentHashMap`. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41041698/2711488) for a discussion of the differences.

Answer (score 5):

You can either chain your grouping collectors which would give you a *multi-level* map. However, this is not ideal if you want to group by say more than 2 fields.

The better option would be to override the `equals` and `hashcode` methods within your `Person` class to define the equality of two given objects which in this case would be all the said fields. Then you can group by `Person` i.e `groupingByConcurrent(Function.identity())` in which case you'll end up with:

```
ConcurrentMap<Person, List<Person>> resultSet = ....
```

Example:

```
class Person {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Person person = (Person) o;

        if (name != null ? !name.equals(person.name) : person.name != null) return false;
        if (uid != null ? !uid.equals(person.uid) : person.uid != null) return false;
        return phone != null ? phone.equals(person.phone) : person.phone == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (uid != null ? uid.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (phone != null ? phone.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    private String name;
    private String uid; // these should be private, don't expose
    private String phone;

   // getters where necessary
   // setters where necessary
}
```

then:

```
ConcurrentMap<Person, List<Person>> resultSet = list.parallelStream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(Function.identity()));
```