# Ideas on how to parallelize this processing (Java8 Futures)?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, future

We have inherited some code that is doing serial processing of a Queue of futures. I'd like to speed it up by running the processing in parallel, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly increment the success / failure counts that we need to track while processing.

This is what existed before:

```
private void flushFutures(final Queue<Future<State>> futures) {
   final Map<String, Integer> someMapA = new HashMap<>();

   while(!futures.isEmpty()) {
      final Future<State> future = futures.poll();

      final State state = future.get();
      switch (state) {
         case SOME_CASE_A:
             // modify someMapA
             break;
         case SOME_CASE_B:
             // modify someMapB
             break;
         //.....
      } 
   }
}
```

So I tried replacing the while loop with a:

`futures.parallelStream().forEach(future -> ...)`
But that leaves me with problems altering state from within a lambda.

Does anyone have tips on how I could better handle these futures to do the same thing as its currently doing, but sequentially, and without the messy adding of the future back into the collection?

Comment: It is unclear what you expect to gain by parallelizing that.  Is the actual implementation of future not calculating the result until GET is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a `forEach`, you could do a `map` on futures.get(), then do a "groupBy" collector using a concurrent hash map.

See: [Java 8 Parallel Stream Concurrent Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848696/java-8-parallel-stream-concurrent-grouping)