# Why my collector method is not processing data parallely?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

> Suppose, however, that the result container used in this reduction was a concurrently modifiable collection -- such as a ConcurrentHashMap. In that case, the parallel invocations of the accumulator could actually deposit their results concurrently into the same shared result container, eliminating the need for the combiner to merge distinct result containers. This potentially provides a boost to the parallel execution performance. We call this a concurrent reduction.

also

> A Collector that supports concurrent reduction is marked with the Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT characteristic. However, a concurrent collection also has a downside. If multiple threads are depositing results concurrently into a shared container, the order in which results are deposited is non-deterministic.

from the [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

this means the collect method with supplier(Concurrent-thread-safe)should have **Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT**. and thus should not maintain any order.

but my code

> 

```
List<Employee> li=Arrays.asList(Employee.emparr());
        System.out.println("printing concurrent result "+li.stream().parallel().unordered().map(s->s.getName()).collect(() -> new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>(),
                (c, e) -> c.add(e.toString()),
                (c1, c2) -> c1.addAll(c2))
                                                  .toString());
```

always prints the result in the encountered order. does this mean my **Collector.Characteristics is not CONCURRENT** ? how to check and set this characteristics ?

Comment: Why would the result not be printed in the encountered order? Parallel just means that it's not guaranteed that the encountered order will be retained, not that it's guaranteed that the resulting order will be different.

Comment: Why do you think your example is collected in a concurrent manner?

Comment: because i used concurrent container.

Comment: You can only define `CONCURRENT` when you create a `Collector::of` with the flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Collector` does not know that you use a concurrent collection provided by `Supplier`, just add the characteristic and see that it is executed the way you want to; for example:

```
String s = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).parallel()
            .unordered()
            .collect(
                    Collector.of(
                            () -> new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>(),
                            (c, e) -> c.add(e.toString()),
                            (c1, c2) -> {
                                c1.addAll(c2);
                                return c1;
                            },
                            Characteristics.CONCURRENT))
```

Comment: Then the combiner function will never be called.

Comment: @Flown of course, but that is entire different story on how `Concurrent` collectors work

Comment: so these characteristics are not inferred from the type of  supplier? what would happen if i use arraylist and set concurrent characteristics ?

Comment: I only wanted to mention it. This is the definition of a concurrent `Collector`.

Comment: @amarnathharish you will get in trouble... you would effectively say that `ArrayList` is more that OK to be updated from multiple threads and things will break. How will they break? Well you could get an Exception, null entries or not all entries in the result List

Comment: @flown why combiner never called?

Comment: @amarnathharish you should also read Flown comment here - a concurrent collect will not call the combiner, and only call the `Supplier` once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888262/what-is-the-difference-between-collectors-toconcurrentmap-and-converting-a-map-t/40888456#40888456

Comment: Perhaps, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41045442/2711488) will also help…