# Does stream use CHARACTERISTICS of the stream source?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

[from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644595/understanding-deeply-spliterator-characteristics)

> > a spliterator reporting either, IMMUTABLE or CONCURRENT, is guaranteed to never throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Of
> >     course, CONCURRENT precludes SIZED semantically, but that has no
> >     consequence to the client code.
>
> In fact, these characteristics are not used for anything in the Stream
>   API, hence, using them inconsistently would never get noticed
>   somewhere.
>
> This is also the explanation why every intermediate operation has the
>   effect of clearing the CONCURRENT, IMMUTABLE and NONNULL
>   characteristics: the Stream implementation doesn’t use them and its
>   internal classes representing the stream state do not maintain them.

if stream doesnt use CHARACTERISTICS from source then how stream works parallely? does stream completely ignores the stream source characteristics?

[from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054008/why-my-collector-method-is-not-processing-data-parallely/52054183#52054183) *Collector does not know that im using  a concurrent collection provided by Supplier, so characteristics are not infered from type of collector container*

1. **under what circumstances stream API considers characteristics ?**
2. **which operation resets which characteristics ?**

Comment: The implementation does not use _these_ characteristics. Other characteristics are used like `SIZED` and `SUBSIZED`.

Comment: why they don't use ? so if I call sorted() on sorted stream its gonna run again and sort? if stream doesn't use characteristics of `spliterator` who else is gonna use them. I personally don't see any reason to use `spliterator` to split a collection and manually optimize it to run on parallel.

Comment: so spliiterator behaves based on its characteristics and these characteristics are forgotten in streams API ?

Comment: The cited statement is specifically talking about `CONCURRENT`, `IMMUTABLE`, and `NONNULL`. In contrast, `ORDERED`, `DISTINCT`, `SORTED`, `SIZED`, and `SUBSIZED` *are* used. And currently unused characteristics might be used in the future.

Comment: "So, if I call sorted() on sorted stream its gonna run again and sort?" AFAIK, if the spliterator is naturally `SORTED` (the associated `Comparator` is `null`) then the `SORTED` characteristic is accounted for in the Stream flags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are asking for *is* possible. The correct verbiage in those answers, would be that *at the moment* those properties are ignored, in some future they might be injected/read/used by stream implementation.

Also in your comments, you say that:

```
someTreeSet().stream()
         .sorted()
         .... some other operations
```

Will call `sorted`. This is simply not true, in this case, that operation will not get called. This is one stream flag that is not ignored and injected into the stream implemntation by `TreeSet`.